# Add weights to documents Lucene 8

Tags: java, lucene

I am currently working on a small search engine for college using **Lucene 8**. I already built it before, but without applying any weights to documents.

I am now required to add the PageRanks of documents as a weight for each document, and I already computed the PageRank values. How can I add a weight to a `Document` object (**not query terms**) in Lucene 8? I looked up many solutions online, but they only work for older versions of Lucene. [Example source](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/building-a-search-index-with-lucene.html#boostingdocumentsinlucene)

Here is my (**updated**) code that generates a `Document` object from a `File` object:

```
public static Document getDocument(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Document d = new Document();

    //adding a field
    FieldType contentType = new FieldType();
    contentType.setStored(true);
    contentType.setTokenized(true);
    contentType.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
    contentType.setStoreTermVectors(true);

    String fileContents = String.join(" ", Files.readAllLines(f.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    d.add(new Field("content", fileContents, contentType));

    //adding other fields, then...

    //the boost coefficient (updated):
    double coef = 1.0 + ranks.get(path);
    d.add(new DoubleDocValuesField("boost", coef));

    return d;

}
```

The issue with my current approach is that I would need a `CustomScoreQuery` object to search the documents, but this is not available in Lucene 8. Also, I don't want to downgrade now to Lucene 7 after all the code I wrote in Lucene 8.

---

**Edit:**

After some (lengthy) research, I added a `DoubleDocValuesField` to each document holding the boost (see updated code above), and used a `FunctionScoreQuery` for searching as advised by @EricLavault. However, **now all my documents have a score of exactly their boost, regardless of the query!** How do I fix that? Here is my searching function:

```
public static TopDocs search(String query, IndexSearcher searcher, String outputFile) {
    try {
        Query q_temp = buildQuery(query); //the original query, was working fine alone

        Query q = new FunctionScoreQuery(q_temp, DoubleValuesSource.fromDoubleField("boost")); //the new query
        q = q.rewrite(DirectoryReader.open(bm25IndexDir));
        TopDocs results = searcher.search(q, 10);

        ScoreDoc[] filterScoreDosArray = results.scoreDocs;
        for (int i = 0; i < filterScoreDosArray.length; ++i) {
            int docId = filterScoreDosArray[i].doc;
            Document d = searcher.doc(docId);

            //here, when printing, I see that the document's score is the same as its "boost" value. WHY??
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("path")+" Score: "+ filterScoreDosArray[i].score);
        }

        return results;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

//function that builds the query, working fine
public static Query buildQuery(String query) {
    try {
        PhraseQuery.Builder builder = new PhraseQuery.Builder();
        TokenStream tokenStream = new EnglishAnalyzer().tokenStream("content", query);
        tokenStream.reset();

        while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
          CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
          builder.add(new Term("content", charTermAttribute.toString()));
        }

        tokenStream.end(); tokenStream.close();
        builder.setSlop(1000);
        PhraseQuery q = builder.build();

        return q;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Luca Kiebel. I just asked a new question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71334341/add-weights-to-documents-lucene8solr-8-while-indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding my edited problem (boost value completely replacing search score instead of boosting it), here is what the [documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core//8_0_0/queries/org/apache/lucene/queries/function/FunctionScoreQuery.html#rewrite-org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader-) says about `FunctionScoreQuery` (emphasis mine):

> A query that wraps another query, and uses a DoubleValuesSource to ***replace or modify*** the wrapped query's score.

So, when does it replace, and when does it modify?

Turns out, the code I was using is for entirely replacing the score by the boost value:

```
Query q = new FunctionScoreQuery(q_temp, DoubleValuesSource.fromDoubleField("boost")); //the new query
```

What I needed to do instead was using the function `boostByValue`, that modifies the searching score (by multiplying the score by the boost value):

```
Query q = FunctionScoreQuery.boostByValue(q_temp, DoubleValuesSource.fromDoubleField("boost"));
```

And now it works! Thanks @EricLavault for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Starting from [Lucene 6.5.0](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_0/changes/Changes.html#v6.5.0.api_changes) :

> Index-time boosts are deprecated. As a replacement,
>   index-time scoring factors should be indexed into a doc value field
>   and combined at query time using eg. FunctionScoreQuery. (Adrien
>   Grand)

The recommendation instead of using index time boost would be to encode scoring factors (ie. length normalization factors) into doc values fields instead. (cf. [LUCENE-6819](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6819))

Comment: I tried going for that, without much success so far. Question updated with the details. I'd be so grateful if you can help!

Comment: I finally managed to fix my issue. Thanks for the help though!